# could not start the service MySQL.error 0

Tags: mysql, windows-xp-sp2

I am getting the following error when I try to configure MySQL instance, could any one help out to resolve this error.

I am using Windows XP SP2.

Comment: Do you have any more info? Are you setting up a new instance? On localhost or a remote computer? Port? etc etc

Comment: Please when asking a system question, *always* add which operating system you're on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you reinstall or upgrade MySQL without first stopping and removing the existing MySQL service and install MySQL using the MySQL Configuration Wizard, you may see this error:
>   Error: Cannot create Windows service for MySql. Error: 0

This occurs when the Configuration Wizard tries to install the service and finds an existing service with the same name.

One solution to this problem is to choose a service name other than mysql when using the configuration wizard. This enables the new service to be installed correctly, but leaves the outdated service in place. Although this is harmless, it is best to remove old services that are no longer in use.

To permanently remove the old mysql service, execute the following command as a user with administrative privileges, on the command-line:

> shell> sc delete mysql
>   [SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

If the sc utility is not available for your version of Windows, download the delsrv utility from http://www.microsoft.com/windows2000/techinfo/reskit/tools/existing/delsrv-o.asp and use the delsrv mysql syntax.

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually when the service doesn't manage to start, there will be more detailed information about what went wrong somewhere:

- In mySQL's `your_hostname_here.err` file
- In the system's error log (In english-language Windows, it's called event log I think)

you need to look there for the reason.